# Bitbucket pipeline: environmental variables in build.gradle file not recognized

Tags: java, gradle, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline script and a version.sh bash script that are playing nicely. The pipeline will call the version script and there are environment variables inside version.sh that are referenced correctly by bitbucket (I added the variables in settings for the repo).

However, I also have variables now in my build.gradle file, but these keep giving me errors in the pipeline when I try a `gradle build`.

The error I keep getting is `could not get unknown property '$context_url' for root project 'my_project' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

The variables are in the artifactory/publish section:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = $context_url
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'repo'
            username = $artifactory_user
            password = $artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried different syntax in the gradle.build file, such as:

- `$context_url`
- `'$context_url'`
- `"$context_url"`

The variables work locally, I have the variables stored in my personal ~/gradle/gradle.properties file.

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: If these are really env variables, please try: `System.getenv('context_url')`

Comment: Have you solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you mess environment variables with gradle properties. If you mean environment variables, then you refer them with:

```
System.getenv('context_url')
```

Typically, environment variable is named with capital letters.

When it comes to gradle properties, if `context_url` is kept in `gradle.properties` file it should just work OOTB. You can try to refer it via `project`, so `project.context_url`. `$context_url`  and `'$context_url'` definitely won't do, since the first one is just a variable with name `$context_url` and the second one an instance of a `String` - string evaluation work with double quotes `"`.

Comment: this makes it pass in Bitbucket pipeline, but fails on command line on local machine (OSX)